# Solve inconsistency in a util (singleton) class

Tags: java, android

I have a util, singleton class, which has some arguments. If some arguments changes through setter-kind of methods, the class notifies subscribers to the changes. Activities, Fragments, and Services can subscribe these changes.
I have a Listener interface inside this class. Subscribers must implement the methods, which the interface defines.

```
private static List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

public static synchronized void addListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public static synchronized void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

As some components subscribe and unsubscribe to and from this class, with the two methods above, listener size changes well. But when some setter-kind method is beeing called, like this:

```
public static synchronized void decrementPosition() {
    if (position > 0) {
        position--;
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.positionChanged(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I see in debug mode, that 'listeners' size is not up-to-date with the additions, and deletions. It seems like 'listeners.remove(listener)' is not working, but when I debug it, it looks like the 'listener' is being removed from the list just fine.
And of course I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {3fc60df} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

from the setter-like method.

Comment: This doesn't look like a singleton to me.  If it was a singleton these methods shouldn't be static, they should be accessed through the single instance of the class.

Comment: Ok, it is not a singleton by definition, but it only has static methods and arguments, so it acts like a singleton class.

Comment: Does it though?  It can call addListener and removeListener at the same time which both modify the same list right?  Would your problem be solved if this was an actual singleton?

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use Thread safe List 
like below 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: I tried it out, but the result is the same. Thx for the suggestion tho